# cannot make drag and drop with svg - react

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, cypress

i have this svg when i hover on it a hand pointer shows then i have to drag and drop it to a target.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/0/svg" class="XVpMgArAdl7U1k9GMrA6" data-testid="item-0">

<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/0/svg" class="XVpMgArAdl7U1k9GMrA6" data-testid="item-1">
```

I have tried everything for it to drag:

```
cy.getBySel('item-0').trigger('pointerdown').trigger("dragstart")
            .trigger("dragleave")
            .trigger("dragover")

cy.getBySel('item-1').click()
            .trigger("dragenter")
            .trigger("dragover")
            .trigger("drop")
            .trigger("dragend");
```

I even tried the drag and drop plugin and using data-transfer but no luck.
It seems like it gets to the pointer down and nothing happens after that.
Does anyone know how i can check what actions are actually being triggered when doing the drag and drop?

Thank you

Comment: What are the event listeners on these elements? You can check by right-click, inspect then go to  "Event Listeners" tab. Hopefully you can see if it listens for `dragstart` or `mousedown`.

Comment: I also wonder about the `.click()` - that looks dangerous in the middle of a drag-drop action (the use will click at start and hold, but cannot do a click in the middle of the action since mouse is already down).

Comment: I see a lot of events..how do you know which one is being triggered first?

Comment: your answer below did not work :(

Comment: i see drag, dragend,dragenter, dragexit, dragleave, dragover, drop,
pointercancel, pointerdown, pointermove, pointerout, pointerover, pointerup,
mousedown, mousemove,mouseout,mouseover, mouseup

Comment: there is dragstart..i missed writing it

Comment: I got this finally but not working:
     cy.getBySel('item-0').trigger('pointerdown').trigger("dragstart")
        cy.getBySel('item-1')
            .trigger("dragover")
            .trigger("drop")
            .trigger("dragend")
I find that the pointerdown is just staying there and if i hover manually i can drag it

Comment: Tbh i see that the item has the hovering effect with the pointerdown but the rest of the events wont fire

Comment: You can try just with `mouse*` events, sounds like they work. Use `mouseover` on the target, since `mousemove` is annoying -  you have to work out where to move relative to the page.

Comment: finally this worked:
 cy.getBySel('item-0')
            .trigger('pointerdown')
            .trigger('dragstart')
        cy.getBySel('item-1').trigger('pointermove').trigger('drop').trigger('dragend').trigger('pointerup')

Comment: Cleaning up irrelevant comments...

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a `dataTransfer` object to work with HTML5 `dragStart` and `drop` events.

For example, if I try this sample page [Drag and Drop: Copy and Move elements with DataTransfer](https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/drag-and-drop/copy-move-DataTransfer.html)

```js
cy.visit('https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/drag-and-drop/copy-move-DataTransfer.html');

const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()

cy.contains('Select this element')
  .should('contain', 'Select this element and drag to the Copy Drop Zone.')
  .as('source')
  .trigger('dragstart', {dataTransfer})

cy.get('[id="dest_copy"]')
  .should('have.text', 'Copy Drop Zone')  // before, this is the exact text 
  .as('target')
  .trigger('drop', {dataTransfer})

// after "copy" operation the source text is also inside the target element
cy.get('@target')
  .should('contain', 'Select this element and drag to the Copy Drop Zone.')
```

So for your test, you can try the following.

But you should also add a test for the effect of the drop. Perhaps it is re-ordering the elements?

```js
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()

cy.getBySel('item-0')
  .trigger('dragstart', {dataTransfer})

cy.getBySel('item-1')
  .trigger('drop', {dataTransfer})

// if drag-drop reorders, test that item-1 is now the first element
cy.get('[data-testid^="item-"]')
  .eq(0)
  .should('have.attr', 'data-testid', 'item-1')
```